# Extracting Timed Metadata from HLS stream ios

Tags: android, video-streaming, metadata, timed

Android is able to play HTTP live streaming (HLS) video streams by specifying URL in a videoView

Is there any way to retrieve timed metadata from HTTP live streaming (HLS) in android?

'MediaMetaDataRetriever' not work.

In iOS i use 'Timed Metadata' with notifications

Answer (score 0):

The default video player cannot retrieve the id3 timed metadata.  [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) can.  Simply integrate into your project and override it's [onMetadata](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer/metadata/MetadataTrackRenderer.MetadataRenderer.html) function.

If you look at the sample player, look at the MetadataTrackRenderer class.  If your hls stream has timed metadata it will fire each time a tagged packet comes in.  I have been working with this lately.  Please feel free to follow up.